Not able to run react-native app on the latest version 0.75.2
I created a project using npx @react-native-community/cli@latest init AwesomeProject. Prior to this "npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli" was run according to https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started-without-a-framework
Then i ran npm start. But when i run npm run android, I'm getting an error. I tried downgrading react-native version and Gradle version but it didn't work.
I am able to run old react native projects. Error is with the new version.
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\UserG\Desktop\PersonalProjects\IntradayMov\IntradayMovers\android\settings.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 6s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Settings file 'C:\Users\UserG\Desktop\PersonalProjects\IntradayMov\IntradayMovers\android\settings.gradle' line: 2 * What went wrong: Plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings'] was not found in any of the following sources: - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace) - Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source) * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 6s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

(Note: No issue found running react-native doctor)
settings.gradle:
pluginManagement { includeBuild("../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin") }
plugins { id("com.facebook.react.settings") }
extensions.configure(com.facebook.react.ReactSettingsExtension){ ex -> ex.autolinkLibrariesFromCommand() }
rootProject.name = 'IntraMovers'
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')

build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.24"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"


Have you tried rebooting your machine? Sometimes that fixes it for me. Also try npx react-native run-android.

Yes, tried both. Not working

That's a GitHub issue, not a question, while the Gradle version is entirely unknown. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+com.facebook.react.settings

https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/1exj4aq/comment/lkjdvjl

@MartinZeitler  ./gradlew clean also gives an error for me. Is there a way to run the project??

@gopalprabhu can you share code inside settings.gradle and build.gradle .

@RohitRajput I have updated the question. please take a look. (Please don't mind the project name in the error and setting.gradle/build.gradle). I had deleted the old project and created a new one but getting the same error.

do you have yarn installed?
